# Module with helper functions to initialize or reinitialize a Slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, revealing-module-pattern

I been getting into javascript patterns and would love to get some feedback. I notice that I got some general helper functions. Is this a good approach of dealing with it?

```
// carousel.js

var Carousel = (function() {
  var timeout = 340;

  function init() {
    applyForTheseQueries();

    $(window).on('resize', Helpers.debounce(function() {
      applyForTheseQueries();
    }, timeout));
  }

  function applyForTheseQueries() {
    var $carousel = $('.js-slick');
    var query = $carousel.data('query');
    var mediaQuery = Helpers.executeFunctionByName(query, window);

    if (mediaQuery && !$carousel.hasClass('init-done')) {
      $carousel.addClass('init-done').slick();
    } else if (!mediaQuery && $carousel.hasClass('init-done')) {
      $carousel.removeClass('init-done').slick('unslick');
    }
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
})();

$(function() {
  Carousel.init();
});



// helpers.js

var Helpers = (function() {
  function executeFunctionByName(functionName, context) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments).splice(2);
    var namespaces = functionName.split(".");
    var func = namespaces.pop();

    for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
      context = context[namespaces[i]];
    }

    return context[func].apply(context, args);
  }

  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
      var context = this;
      var args = arguments;

      var later = function() {
        timeout = null;
        if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
      };

      var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
      clearTimeout(timeout);
      timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);

      if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
  };

  return {
    executeFunctionByName: executeFunctionByName,
    debounce: debounce
  };
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach seems fine. I did notice the following loop in `Helpers. executeFunctionByName()`:

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
>   context = context[namespaces[i]];
> }
> return context[func].apply(context, args);
> ```

Doesn't that just set `context` equal to the last element in `namespaces`? Why not just use a simple assignment without a loop?

---

The value for the timeout

> ```
>  var timeout = 340;
> ```

Could be declared with all capitals as is idiomatic in JavaScript and many C-based languages, as well as a more descriptive name:

```
 const RESIZE_TIMEOUT = 340;
```

---

There are a few things that could be simplified.

In `Carousel.init` the resize callback could be simplified from

> ```
> $(window).on('resize', Helpers.debounce(function() {
>   applyForTheseQueries();
> }, timeout));
> ```

To this:

```
$(window).on('resize', Helpers.debounce(applyForTheseQueries, timeout));
```

And if [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) syntax is supported, then [object initializer shorthand notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) can be used - instead of :

> ```
> return {
>   init: init
> }
> ```

just use:

```
return {
  init
}
```

And instead of

> ```
> return {
>   executeFunctionByName: executeFunctionByName,
>   debounce: debounce
> };
> ```

Simply to

```
return {
  executeFunctionByName,
  debounce
};
```

Another [ecmascript-6](/questions/tagged/ecmascript-6) feature that could be used is the `for...of` loop. Instead of

> ```
> for (var i = 0; i < namespaces.length; i++) {
>   context = context[namespaces[i]];
> }
> ```

Simplify this to

```
for (const namespace of namespaces) {
  context = context[namespace];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a nice, clean way to do it. I do not see smth wrong here. You have your helper methods isolated, they are exposed correctly, and the methods within are DRY, they only care for what they get from arguments, and they return one thing only.

Maybe you have to get sure that nothing breaks if `init()` gets called for more than one times, that is the one thing I would suggest.